# Why 127.0.0.1:port is not mapping to localhost:port?

Tags: asp.net, url, twitter, localhost

I am trying to configure twitter application for ASP.NET MVC and I had to specify Website for APP in twitter. Since this is test/demo development, I don't have real fully qualified URL so I am using localhost:52634/ . Since localhost does not qualify fully qualified name, I replaced it with 127.0.0.1:52634 but 127.0.0.1:52634 is not working and giving me Bad request 400 error. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify 127.0.0.1:port in twitter, as twitter wont "see" you as 127.0.0.1, but sees itself :)

127.0.0.1 is only valid in your pc, no one(twitter) can access it. Find your external ip (go to www.whatismyip.com and see your external IP), and append that ip with your port '52634', like http://xx.xx.xx.xx:52634/ and update this into your twitter application.

Comment: He would probably need port forwarding if natted too and possibly a firewall rule exception..